# using struts property in another struts tag

Tags: java, struts, common-controls

I am using Struts1;
I am iterating through a list using logic:iterate

```
<logic:iterate .... indexId="index">
```

and i would like to use the "index" property as an argument to be passed to a javascript function while pressing a button

```
<ctrl:button ... onclick="return functioncall (index)"/>
```

how is the sitax to access the correct "index" property inside the ctrl:button tag?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself:

I can access the "index" struts variable using the jsp-expression language. The syntax is

To make it work, I have to set 
    <%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>